# How to change ulimit value in limits.conf using sed command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, text-processing

I want to append changes in `limits.conf` if not exists using shell script. Two cases:

1. If limit not specified, I have to add using **sed**.
2. If limit exists, it should not change.

```
*   soft   nofile  100000
*   hard   nofile  150000
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question. That is just a straight-forward **sed** substitution.  _This_ question requires a test of whether or not certain information is already present in `limits.conf` and, if not, then append a new line.

Comment: And in the linked question, [How do I use sed to change my configuration files, with flexible keys and values?](//stackoverflow.com/q/5955548), none of the answers actually work.  The OP's requirement there was that "... both `central.database` and `SQLTEST` come from bash variables".  However, all the answers assumed the hard-coded value of `central.database` or whatever so that they could manually escape the dot `.`, rather than dealing with an arbitrary bash variable. (Indeed, many answerers forgot that `.` was special in **sed**.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **bash** script will add `$LINE_TO_APPEND` to the end of `limits.conf` when the given type and item is not already present in `limits.conf`:

```
LINE_TO_APPEND='*               hard    nofile          512'
read -a line_array <<< "$LINE_TO_APPEND"
line_type=${line_array[1]} # consists of just normal characters
line_item=${line_array[2]} # consists of just normal characters
if [[ -z $(grep "$line_type  *$line_item" limits.conf) ]]; then
   echo "$LINE_TO_APPEND" >> limits.conf
fi
```

If you want a more purely **sed** approach, the following less-generic command with hard-coded fields will work (I got caught up in "escaping hell" trying to use `$`; I'll try revisiting this answer later!):

```
sed -i 'H;1h;$!d;x;/soft  *nofile/!s/$/\n*   soft   nofile  100000/' limits.conf
```

Explanation of **sed** solution:

- `H;1h;$!d;x` read entire file into pattern buffer (see [sed: read whole file into pattern space without failing on single-line input](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/182153))
- `/soft  *nofile/!` if file ***does not*** contain `soft nofile` (arbitrary spacing),
- `s/$/\n*   soft   nofile  100000/` then add `*   soft   nofile  100000` to the end
- `-i` change file in place